# Displaying caption for this image plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, css, jquery-plugins

This [plugins](http://osvaldas.info/examples/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly/) default technique of displaying caption involves, extracting the content of the "alt" attribute from the corresponding image which it targets.

```
captionOn = function()
{
    var description = $( 'a[href="' + $( '#imagelightbox' ).attr( 'src' ) + '"] img' ).attr( 'alt' );
    if( description.length > 0 )
    $( '<div id="imagelightbox-caption">' + description + '</div>' ).appendTo( 'body' );
},
captionOff = function()
{
    $( '#imagelightbox-caption' ).remove();
},
```

The design I am working on requires more content to be included for the caption, like comments, date, etc.

So obviously those details can't be included in the "alt" tag of an image. Will require separate "div" for that.

How can I modify the above "description" variable in the JS which would pick the "div#caption" for that image, and display its content?

```
<a href="cwc/21.jpg" data-imagelightbox="d" class="img-wr"><img class="social-img" src="cwc/21.jpg" alt="lorem sit amet" /><div id="caption">lorem sit amet</div></a>
```

Since this is an image gallery, there will be lot of that HTML code replicated. So the concern I am facing is that when somebody clicks that image, it should only show the "div#caption" for that particular image.

http://codepen.io/arjunmenon/pen/NqqyJe - Default implementation

```js
$(function() {
  // ACTIVITY INDICATOR

  var activityIndicatorOn = function() {
      $('<div id="imagelightbox-loading"><div></div></div>').appendTo('body');
    },
    activityIndicatorOff = function() {
      $('#imagelightbox-loading').remove();
    },


    // OVERLAY

    overlayOn = function() {
      $('<div id="imagelightbox-overlay"></div>').appendTo('body');
    },
    overlayOff = function() {
      $('#imagelightbox-overlay').remove();
    },


    // CLOSE BUTTON

    closeButtonOn = function(instance) {
      $('<button type="button" id="imagelightbox-close" title="Close"></button>').appendTo('body').on('click touchend', function() {
        $(this).remove();
        instance.quitImageLightbox();
        return false;
      });
    },
    closeButtonOff = function() {
      $('#imagelightbox-close').remove();
    },


    // CAPTION

    captionOn = function() {
      var description = $('a[href="' + $('#imagelightbox').attr('src') + '"] img').attr('alt');
      if (description.length > 0)
        $('<div id="imagelightbox-caption">' + description + '</div>').appendTo('body');
    },
    captionOff = function() {
      $('#imagelightbox-caption').remove();
    },


    // NAVIGATION

    navigationOn = function(instance, selector) {
      var images = $(selector);
      if (images.length) {
        var nav = $('<div id="imagelightbox-nav"></div>');
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
          nav.append('<button type="button"></button>');

        nav.appendTo('body');
        nav.on('click touchend', function() {
          return false;
        });

        var navItems = nav.find('button');
        navItems.on('click touchend', function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if (images.eq($this.index()).attr('href') != $('#imagelightbox').attr('src'))
              instance.switchImageLightbox($this.index());

            navItems.removeClass('active');
            navItems.eq($this.index()).addClass('active');

            return false;
          })
          .on('touchend', function() {
            return false;
          });
      }
    },
    navigationUpdate = function(selector) {
      var items = $('#imagelightbox-nav button');
      items.removeClass('active');
      items.eq($(selector).filter('[href="' + $('#imagelightbox').attr('src') + '"]').index(selector)).addClass('active');
    },
    navigationOff = function() {
      $('#imagelightbox-nav').remove();
    },


    // ARROWS

    arrowsOn = function(instance, selector) {
      var $arrows = $('<button type="button" class="imagelightbox-arrow imagelightbox-arrow-left"></button><button type="button" class="imagelightbox-arrow imagelightbox-arrow-right"></button>');

      $arrows.appendTo('body');

      $arrows.on('click touchend', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this),
          $target = $(selector + '[href="' + $('#imagelightbox').attr('src') + '"]'),
          index = $target.index(selector);

        if ($this.hasClass('imagelightbox-arrow-left')) {
          index = index - 1;
          if (!$(selector).eq(index).length)
            index = $(selector).length;
        } else {
          index = index + 1;
          if (!$(selector).eq(index).length)
            index = 0;
        }

        instance.switchImageLightbox(index);
        return false;
      });
    },
    arrowsOff = function() {
      $('.imagelightbox-arrow').remove();
    };


  // WITH ACTIVITY INDICATION

  $('a[data-imagelightbox="a"]').imageLightbox({
    onLoadStart: function() {
      activityIndicatorOn();
    },
    onLoadEnd: function() {
      activityIndicatorOff();
    },
    onEnd: function() {
      activityIndicatorOff();
    }
  });


  // WITH OVERLAY & ACTIVITY INDICATION

  $('a[data-imagelightbox="b"]').imageLightbox({
    onStart: function() {
      overlayOn();
    },
    onEnd: function() {
      overlayOff();
      activityIndicatorOff();
    },
    onLoadStart: function() {
      activityIndicatorOn();
    },
    onLoadEnd: function() {
      activityIndicatorOff();
    }
  });


  // WITH "CLOSE" BUTTON & ACTIVITY INDICATION

  var instanceC = $('a[data-imagelightbox="c"]').imageLightbox({
    quitOnDocClick: false,
    onStart: function() {
      closeButtonOn(instanceC);
    },
    onEnd: function() {
      closeButtonOff();
      activityIndicatorOff();
    },
    onLoadStart: function() {
      activityIndicatorOn();
    },
    onLoadEnd: function() {
      activityIndicatorOff();
    }
  });


  // WITH CAPTION & ACTIVITY INDICATION

  $('a[data-imagelightbox="d"]').imageLightbox({
    onLoadStart: function() {
      captionOff();
      activityIndicatorOn();
    },
    onLoadEnd: function() {
      captionOn();
      activityIndicatorOff();
    },
    onEnd: function() {
      captionOff();
      activityIndicatorOff();
    }
  });


  // WITH ARROWS & ACTIVITY INDICATION

  var selectorG = 'a[data-imagelightbox="g"]';
  var instanceG = $(selectorG).imageLightbox({
    onStart: function() {
      arrowsOn(instanceG, selectorG);
    },
    onEnd: function() {
      arrowsOff();
      activityIndicatorOff();
    },
    onLoadStart: function() {
      activityIndicatorOn();
    },
    onLoadEnd: function() {
      $('.imagelightbox-arrow').css('display', 'block');
      activityIndicatorOff();
    }
  });


  // WITH NAVIGATION & ACTIVITY INDICATION

  var selectorE = 'a[data-imagelightbox="e"]';
  var instanceE = $(selectorE).imageLightbox({
    onStart: function() {
      navigationOn(instanceE, selectorE);
    },
    onEnd: function() {
      navigationOff();
      activityIndicatorOff();
    },
    onLoadStart: function() {
      activityIndicatorOn();
    },
    onLoadEnd: function() {
      navigationUpdate(selectorE);
      activityIndicatorOff();
    }
  });


  // ALL COMBINED

  var selectorF = 'a[data-imagelightbox="f"]';
  var instanceF = $(selectorF).imageLightbox({
    onStart: function() {
      overlayOn();
      closeButtonOn(instanceF);
      arrowsOn(instanceF, selectorF);
    },
    onEnd: function() {
      overlayOff();
      captionOff();
      closeButtonOff();
      arrowsOff();
      activityIndicatorOff();
    },
    onLoadStart: function() {
      captionOff();
      activityIndicatorOn();
    },
    onLoadEnd: function() {
      captionOn();
      activityIndicatorOff();
      $('.imagelightbox-arrow').css('display', 'block');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#imagelightbox {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  touch-action: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3.125em rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  /* 50 */
  box-shadow: 0 0 3.125em rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  /* 50 */
}
/* ACTIVITY INDICATION */

#imagelightbox-loading,
#imagelightbox-loading div {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#imagelightbox-loading {
  width: 2.5em;
  /* 40 */
  height: 2.5em;
  /* 40 */
  background-color: #444;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10003;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 0.625em;
  /* 10 */
  margin: -1.25em 0 0 -1.25em;
  /* 20 */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  /* 40 */
  box-shadow: 0 0 2.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  /* 40 */
}
#imagelightbox-loading div {
  width: 1.25em;
  /* 20 */
  height: 1.25em;
  /* 20 */
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation: imagelightbox-loading .5s ease infinite;
  animation: imagelightbox-loading .5s ease infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes imagelightbox-loading {
  from {
    opacity: .5;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.75);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    opacity: .5;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.75);
  }
}
@keyframes imagelightbox-loading {
  from {
    opacity: .5;
    transform: scale(.75);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    opacity: .5;
    transform: scale(.75);
  }
}
/* OVERLAY */

#imagelightbox-overlay {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
/* "CLOSE" BUTTON */

#imagelightbox-close {
  width: 2.5em;
  /* 40 */
  height: 2.5em;
  /* 40 */
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #666;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10002;
  top: 2.5em;
  /* 40 */
  right: 2.5em;
  /* 40 */
  -webkit-transition: color .3s ease;
  transition: color .3s ease;
}
#imagelightbox-close:hover,
#imagelightbox-close:focus {
  background-color: #111;
}
#imagelightbox-close:before,
#imagelightbox-close:after {
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
#imagelightbox-close:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#imagelightbox-close:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
/* CAPTION */

#imagelightbox-caption {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10001;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0.625em;
}
/* 10 */

#caption {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10001;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0.625em;
}
/* NAVIGATION */

#imagelightbox-nav {
  background-color: #444;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10001;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 3.75em;
  /* 60 */
  padding: 0.313em;
  /* 5 */
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#imagelightbox-nav button {
  width: 1em;
  /* 20 */
  height: 1em;
  /* 20 */
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.313em;
  /* 5 */
}
#imagelightbox-nav button.active {
  background-color: #fff;
}
/* ARROWS */

.imagelightbox-arrow {
  width: 3.75em;
  /* 60 */
  height: 7.5em;
  /* 120 */
  background-color: #444;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10001;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -3.75em;
  /* 60 */
}
.imagelightbox-arrow:hover,
.imagelightbox-arrow:focus {
  background-color: #666;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
.imagelightbox-arrow:active {
  background-color: #111;
}
.imagelightbox-arrow-left {
  left: 2.5em;
  /* 40 */
}
.imagelightbox-arrow-right {
  right: 2.5em;
  /* 40 */
}
.imagelightbox-arrow:before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 1em solid transparent;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: -0.125em;
  /* 2 */
}
.imagelightbox-arrow-left:before {
  border-left: none;
  border-right-color: #fff;
  margin-left: -0.313em;
  /* 5 */
}
.imagelightbox-arrow-right:before {
  border-right: none;
  border-left-color: #fff;
  margin-right: -0.313em;
  /* 5 */
}
#imagelightbox-loading,
#imagelightbox-overlay,
#imagelightbox-close,
#imagelightbox-caption,
#imagelightbox-nav,
.imagelightbox-arrow {
  -webkit-animation: fade-in .25s linear;
  animation: fade-in .25s linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 41.250em)
/* 660 */

{
  #container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #imagelightbox-close {
    top: 1.25em;
    /* 20 */
    right: 1.25em;
    /* 20 */
  }
  #imagelightbox-nav {
    bottom: 1.25em;
    /* 20 */
  }
  .imagelightbox-arrow {
    width: 2.5em;
    /* 40 */
    height: 3.75em;
    /* 60 */
    margin-top: -2.75em;
    /* 30 */
  }
  .imagelightbox-arrow-left {
    left: 1.25em;
    /* 20 */
  }
  .imagelightbox-arrow-right {
    right: 1.25em;
    /* 20 */
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 20em)
/* 320 */

{
  .imagelightbox-arrow-left {
    left: 0;
  }
  .imagelightbox-arrow-right {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="http://osvaldas.info/examples/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly/full/7.jpg" data-imagelightbox="d">
      <img src="http://osvaldas.info/examples/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly/thumb/7.jpg" alt="The end of the railway" />
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="http://osvaldas.info/examples/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly/full/8.jpg" data-imagelightbox="d">
      <img src="http://osvaldas.info/examples/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly/thumb/8.jpg" alt="Railway in Klaipeda" />
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="http://osvaldas.info/examples/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly/full/9.jpg" data-imagelightbox="d">
      <img src="http://osvaldas.info/examples/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly/thumb/9.jpg" alt="Herkaus Manto street in Klaipeda" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="http://osvaldas.info/examples/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly/imagelightbox.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. You should be able to use `$(this)` with `parent()/children()` though. You want to automatically add the caption `div` for each `img` surrounded in an `a` tag?

Comment: Sorry, if my style of writing was confusing. Please mention what part is it and I would happily edit it. thanks

Comment: If you look at the first code snippet, there is a "description" variable. That selects the "alt" attribute of the particular image and shows it as a caption. My aim is to show  the content of a separate "div" associated with that image alone, which would contain more details corresponding to the image. Those details can't be assigned in the "alt" tag. Need separate div.

Comment: Well the confusing part is your html has an `a` which inside has and `img` and a `div` with `id="caption"`, but in the javascript you're appending a caption div to the body. Are those two divs separate divs? If you have let's say 10 images and add that div to the corresponding structure, then it'd be easy to keep track of which div belongs to which image. If you must add them to the body then you can add a `data-*` tag to that div which will have a reference to the corresponding image or store the reference in an array or something.

Comment: Well thats the way the plugin works. By having an "a" tag pointing to a full screen image, it displays it over anything in the body tag. You can try that. I have also  updated the question. i guess it will be more legible now.

Comment: The "div#caption" inside the "a" tag is the one I modified. Originally the html code did not had it. Since it was just picking up the content for the caption from the "alt" attribute of the image.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/5f0xwp3e/1/ Is it what you want or somehow close?

Comment: No. Please use Codepen. Jsfiddle wont load the plugin from external source.

Comment: I just want to display comments for that image. I was explaining using the caption code to give an understanding of the code structure.

Comment: `alt` attribute cant hold anything useful other than a small line of text. Isn't it, obviously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
var description = $( 'a[href="' + $( '#imagelightbox' ).attr( 'src' ) + '"] img' ).attr( 'alt' );
```

...with this one:

```
var description = $( 'a[href="' + $( '#imagelightbox' ).attr( 'src' ) + '"] ' ).find( '#caption' ).html();
```

Comment: I may be missing something in the code but since you can have only one unique id for each div (i.e., #caption), how will this method show a caption for each image, since you would need a different id for each image caption div?

Comment: It instantiates an element at a time.